# Text area with html tag in coldfusion

Tags: html, coldfusion

I have a text area, I want to show the data entered in text area as it is.

Ex: if I entered

123
345
I want show output in 2 lines and if entered any html tag like  inside text area, need to show out put in bold

Any way to do it in coldfusion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, but what have you tried so far? Please show us some code.

Comment: I got few solutions 1. Use <pre></pre> tag   2. htmlcodeFormat() ect... Thank you for checking my issue

Comment: How did those solutions turn out?